# CMake include library in another library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a given **project structure**

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── lib
│   ├── lodepng
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   └── src
│   │       ├── lodepng.cpp
│   │       └── lodepng.h
│   └── pixel_reader
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       └── src
│           ├── hello.cpp
│           └── hello.h
├── main.cpp
```

With the following CMakeLists

**./CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(pov_system VERSION 1.0)

add_subdirectory(lib/lodepng)
add_subdirectory(lib/pixel_reader)

add_executable(pov_system main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(pixel_reader PRIVATE lodepng)
target_link_libraries(pov_system PRIVATE pixel_reader)
```

**./lodepng/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(
    lodepng
    src/lodepng.cpp
    src/lodepng.h
)

target_include_directories(lodepng PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
```

**./pixel_reader/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(
    pixel_reader SHARED
    src/hello.cpp
    src/hello.h
)

target_include_directories(pixel_reader PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
```

As one can see, I try to link the 'lodepng' library to the 'pixel_reader' library and include the 'lodepng.h' to the 'hello.h' file.
But at the moment I get the following error while trying to build the project.

```
[build] <path-to-project>/pov_system/lib/pixel_reader/src/hello.h:2:10: fatal error: lodepng.h: No such file or directory
[build]     2 | #include "lodepng.h"
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
```

**Question**

Why is my code not finding the 'lodepng.h' file or (and even more important) is it a good practice to link from one library to another?

Maybe two really simple questions, but just started to dive into the world of CMake, Compiling, etc... and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If pixel_reader depends on loadpng it should include that dependency itself in it's own CMakeList.txt, not rely on it being done from pov_system.

Comment: `target_link_libraries(pixel_reader PRIVATE lodepng)` must be in `pixel_reader/CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: Did you try simply changing `PRIVATE` to `PUBLIC` in your first `target_link_libraries` call? e.g.: `target_link_libraries(pixel_reader PUBLIC lodepng)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is my code not finding the 'lodepng.h' file or (and even more important)

Because you probably didn't give it correct path. One way to fix that would be to give the exact path in `hello.h`

`#include "../../lodepng/src/lodepng.h`

Second way is to use `target_include_directories`:

```
target_include_directories(pixel_reader PUBLIC "../../lodepng/src/")
```

> is it a good practice to link from one library to another?

It depends on your project. If library A *requires* library B, then yes, it is okay in my opinion.

More importantly, you are creating the target in the wrong place i.e., in the root CMakeLists file. It must be done in the directory in which target is created.

**./pixel_reader/CMakeLists.txt**

```
# create target
add_library(
    pixel_reader SHARED
    src/hello.cpp
    src/hello.h
)

target_link_libraries(pixel_reader PRIVATE lodepng) #link library where target is created
target_include_directories(pixel_reader PUBLIC "../../lodepng/src/")

target_include_directories(pixel_reader PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pixel_reader library target possibly needs lodepng.h header to compile, because it depends on it.

something like

```
target_include_directories(pixel_reader PUBLIC "PATH_TO_LODE_PNG_HEADER_DIRECTORY")
```

could solve this problem.

Comment: Actually it is doing the trick. But why do I have to include the directory? I don't have to include the directory if I try to include pixle_reader to my executable.

And is it considered to be a good practice to include libraries into other libraries?

Comment: Well, it is necessary to include lodepng.h. You should know something about interface and signatures of fuctions you are going to use. A practice i often see is placing include common include files in a pre-defined directory, like ./Include. And it is possible, but usually different libraries do different things.

Comment: Some useful links here 

https://www.calleerlandsson.com/the-four-stages-of-compiling-a-c-program/


http://docencia.ac.upc.edu/FIB/USO/Bibliografia/unix-c-libraries.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate your answer and the provided links.